# return view missing id in url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a website that allows to modify records. the page url of a record goes in the format /edit/112.

I have 2 buttons (save / delete) on the command which uses a multibutton command to forward the data to the correct action. when forwarded to the save action I then check to see if the modelstate is valid. The problem I am having that if the model state is false i want to redirect back to the edit view with the model and also keeping the id still intact. Problem I am having at the moment that the URL id is lost on returning to the view.

here is my code

```
 [HttpPost]
    [MultipleButton(Name = "action", Argument = "Update")]
    public ActionResult Update(CustomerViewModel model)
    {
        TempData.Keep();
        model.CustomerTypes = TempData["dropdownlist"] as IEnumerable<CustomerTypes>;


        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View("Edit", model);
        }
        var status = _customerService.UpdateCustomer(model.ToServiceModel());

        if (status.Result) return View("Index");
        ModelState.AddModelError("Model", status.Message);
        return View("Edit", model);
    }
```

any help...

Comment: Have you managed to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a bunch of custom code that's all hidden there, so it's hard to say for sure, but generally, for a route to contain an id, it needs two pieces:

1. Your action needs to be able to accept the id:

   ```
   public ActionResult Update(int id, CustomerViewModel model)
   ```
2. You must pass the id when generating the URL for the route (either in `Html.ActionLink`, etc. or `Url.Action`, etc.:

   ```
   @Html.ActionLink("Update this!", "Update", "MyController", new { id = Model.Id })
   ```